# Log4j Version 1 Custom Throwable (stacktrace) Renderer for removing new line characters

Tags: java, scala, log4j, splunk

We are trying to customize Log4j version 1 appenders which generate the output in Json format that there are no new line characters including Stacktrace, i.e., we read these logs in Splunk and need all the data in one line so that Splunk can parse the Json properly. If we end up generating multiline Json, Splunk fails to understand the Json correctly, Splunk dashboards won't work correctly.

Added a ThrowableRender to strip the new line characters inside the stacktrace

```
class Log4JThrowableRenderer extends ThrowableRender {
 override def doRender(throwable: Throwable) : Array[String] = {
  
   // Kept it simple for now, could have optimized the replace statements
   val defaultRepresentation: Array[String] = new DefaultThrowableRenderer().doRender(throwable)
   val newRepresentation: String = defaultRepresentation.map( l => {
      l.replace('\n','|').replace('\r', '|')
   }).mkString("|)
      
   Array(newRepresentation)
}
```

Updated the log4j appenders

```
log4j.throwableRenderer=com.foo.Log4JThrowableRenderer
log4j.appender.fooAppender.layout.ConversionPattern={"timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd}", "stackTrace":"%throwable" } // simplified
```

And we are able to remove the new line characters from Stacktrace in Json output, except that the ending "}" bracket ends up in new line as in

```
    {"timestamp": "2020-01-01", "stackTrace": "..| ... |... |...| 
"}
```

Not sure how to get all in one line, any ideas?

Comment: I do not know how to fix your problem. However, you can avoid it by using `SplunkHttp` appender from https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/java/logging-java/howtouseloggingjava/enableloghttpjava